# PyCuda: sparse matrix vector multiplication for non-square matrices?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, pycuda

I'm trying to implement a sparse matrix vector operation using pycuda.  The only example I've been able to find for this is on their wiki, which implements a sparse solve routine, however I'm just interested in the matrix-vector multiplication part.

The matrix is a block diagonal NxM matrix, and I have a dense length M vector.

Below is some dummy code that does what I want, but should run (and fail) for anyone.  It makes a block diagonal matrix using the scipy sparse routine that is 100, (100x7) matrices in a block diagonal format.

I then call this 'PacketedSpMV' function which is the thing that fails with the error: `only square matrices are supported`

I cannot find any useful documentation for what this function does, or if there is a different version that works for non square matrices.  I also don't know what this permute thing is doing, however it was used in an answer to a different question on how to do a square matrix-vector operation.  I also can't find any useful examples where, for example, once the spmv object has been created, I can update the contents with different matrices that have the same structure, rather than recalling this function every time (which seems to be slow).

First things first though, is there no non-square way to do this? Or do I need to pad everything with zeros and do a sparse-sparse matrix-vector multiplication, which seems bizarre.

Thanks, and apologies for the basic question.

```
from __future__ import division
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import numpy
from pycuda.sparse.packeted import PacketedSpMV
import scipy.sparse as ss

A=np.ones([100,10,7])
M = ss.block_diag(A, format="csr")

spmv = PacketedSpMV(M, False, M.dtype)

rhs = numpy.random.rand(spmv.shape[0]).astype(spmv.dtype)
rhs_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(rhs)


xp = spmv.permute(rhs_gpu)
yp = spmv(xp)
y = spmv.unpermute(yp)
```

Comment: scikits-cuda has [python wrappers for cusparse](https://github.com/lebedov/scikit-cuda/blob/master/skcuda/cusparse.py).  Maybe worth a look.  You can certainly do non-square spmv with cusparse